# How to deal with Preloader using the Beautifulsoup or Python without using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the products on the websites.
Few of the website loads all the products in the site, few are not.
found the reason because element hidden condition

```
<div class="o-preloader hidden">Preloader</div>**
```

website:https://www.ponds.com/us/en/products.html

"show more button" to know more products
the total number of products 16.

Comment: Please include the code for your current attempt

Answer (score 0):

Seeing in the URL their are only 2 pages loading and they are fetching data via ajax call and getting json which has a list with name `productList` which as all your content. Follow the below code to get titles of all products and you could even modify to get other details:

Ajax URL:[Click here](https://www.ponds.com/us/en/products/_jcr_content/flexi_hero_par/productlistingv2_884.data.json?pn=1)

```
import requests

for i in range(1,3):
    data=requests.get(f"https://www.ponds.com/us/en/products/_jcr_content/flexi_hero_par/productlistingv2_884.data.json?pn={i}").json()
    for j in data["data"]["productListingV2"]["products"]["productList"]:
        print(j["title"])
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Let me know if you have any questions :)